# Android studio crashing after updating sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.3

This happens after I updated Android Studio from 2.1.2 to 2.3. The setup of my system is:

```
Android Studio 2.3  Build #AI-162.3764568 
JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
OS: Ubuntu 16.10 64 bits
```

After I update the SDK, the UI of android studio freeze and the following is the logged error:

```
[  41743]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FN_AAPT2 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FN_AAPT2
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeAndWait(LaterInvocator.java:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:634)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.ApplicationUtils.invokeWriteActionAndWait(ApplicationUtils.java:39)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallComponentsPath$SetPreference.apply(InstallComponentsPath.java:373)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallComponentsPath$SetPreference.apply(InstallComponentsPath.java:362)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$FunctionWrapper.perform(InstallOperation.java:177)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation$OperationChain.perform(InstallOperation.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.InstallOperation.execute(InstallOperation.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallComponentsPath.runLongOperation(InstallComponentsPath.java:251)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ConsolidatedProgressStep.doLongRunningOperation(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:78)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ConsolidatedProgressStep.access$000(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:32)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.ConsolidatedProgressStep$1.run(ConsolidatedProgressStep.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost$LongRunningOperationWrapper.run(FirstRunWizardHost.java:430)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FN_AAPT2
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.<init>(BuildToolInfo.java:352)
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.fromStandardDirectoryLayout(BuildToolInfo.java:224)
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.fromLocalPackage(BuildToolInfo.java:238)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getLatestBuildTool(AndroidSdkHandler.java:772)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.PlatformTarget.<init>(PlatformTarget.java:144)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetMap(AndroidTargetManager.java:94)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargets(AndroidTargetManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getTargetCollection(AndroidSdkData.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getTargets(AndroidSdkData.java:176)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.createAndroidSdkPerAndroidTarget(IdeSdks.java:348)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:294)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.setAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:224)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallComponentsPath$SetPreference.lambda$apply$0(InstallComponentsPath.java:374)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
    at com.android.tools.idea.ui.ApplicationUtils$1.run(ApplicationUtils.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[  41747]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Android Studio 2.3  Build #AI-162.3764568 
[  41747]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
[  41748]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[  41748]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
[  41748]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - OS: Linux 
[  41748]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Last Action:
```

Can anyone provide a suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the previous version of Android Studio(If you have). And copy the latest version at `/usr/local` then change directory `cd android-studio/bin/` and finally start Android Studio with `./studio.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I made a stupid mistake;
  I deleted the directory of an old AndroidStudio version while I was in that folder in the terminal.
  After installing the new version in the same directory I tried executing bin/studio.sh.  It did not work and I received the same errors.
  Everything was fine after reentering the directory.

Maybe this will help somebody who runs into the same problem when upgrading AndroidStudio versions.